# How to force authentication to run so that the principal is available for other ASP.NET Core middleware?

Tags: identityserver4

I am trying to add a middleware to implement throttling in my Web API based on client id. This Web API is protected by Identity Server 4 and the JWT authentication handler.

The problem is that Context.User.Claims is always empty when my middleware runs.
I understand that the Jwt handler only gets called when the request hits the Authorize attribute.

Thus, my question is, how can I "force" the Jwt handler to run sooner in the pipeline so that my middleware gets the call after the token is validated and the client_id claim is available in the context principal?

Thanks for any help you can give me.

The code that setups the Web API is as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Validation

    SmartGuard.NotNull(() => services, services);

    // Log

    this.Logger.LogTrace("Application services configuration starting.");

    // Configuration

    services
        .AddOptions()
        .Configure<ServiceConfiguration>(this.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(ServiceConfiguration)))
        .Configure<TelemetryConfiguration>(this.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(TelemetryConfiguration)))
        .Configure<TableStorageServiceConfiguration>(this.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(TableStorageServiceConfiguration)))
        .UseConfigurationSecrets();

    ServiceConfiguration serviceConfiguration = services.ResolveConfiguration<ServiceConfiguration>();

    // Telemetry (Application Insights)

    services.AddTelemetryForApplicationInsights();

    // Memory cache

    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

    // MVC

    services.AddMvc();

    // Identity

    services
        .AddAuthorization(
            (options) =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(
                    Constants.Policies.Settings,
                    (policy) =>
                    {
                        policy.RequireClaim(Constants.ClaimTypes.Scope, Scopes.Settings);
                    });
            });

    // NOTE:
    // We are using the JWT Bearer handler here instead of the IdentityServer handler
    // because version 2.3.0 does not handle bearer challenges correctly.
    // For more info: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2047
    // This is supposed to be fixed in version 2.4.0.

    services
        .AddAuthentication(Constants.AuthenticationSchemes.Bearer)
        .AddJwtBearer(
            (options) =>
            {
                options.Authority = serviceConfiguration.IdentityServerBaseUri;
                options.Audience = Constants.ApiName;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
                options.RefreshOnIssuerKeyNotFound = true;
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
                {
                    OnChallenge = HandleChallenge
                };
            });

    // Web API Versioning

    services.AddApiVersioning(
        (options) =>
        {
            options.DefaultApiVersion = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiVersion(ApiVersions.DefaultVersion.Major, ApiVersions.DefaultVersion.Minor);
            options.ReportApiVersions = true;
            options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
        });

    // Setup Throttling

    services
        .AddThrottling()
        .AddClientRateHandler(this.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(ClientRateThrottlingOptions)));

    // Routes analyzer
    // Creates the /routes route that lists all the routes configured

    services.AddRouteAnalyzerInDevelopment(this.CurrentEnvironment);

    // Add the managers

    services.AddManagers();

    // Background services

    services.AddBackgroundService<StorageSetupService>();

    // Log

    this.Logger.LogTrace("Application services configuration completed.");
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // Validation

    SmartGuard.NotNull(() => app, app);
    SmartGuard.NotNull(() => env, env);

    // Log

    this.Logger.LogTrace("Application configuration starting.");

    // Error handling (Telemetry)

    app.UseTelemetryExceptionHandler();

    // Authentication

    app.UseAuthentication();

    // Register the throttling middleware

    app.UseThrottling();

    // MVC

    app.UseMvc(
        (routes) =>
        {
            // Routes analyzer

            routes.MapRouteAnalyzerInDevelopment(env);
        });

    // Log

    this.Logger.LogTrace("Application configuration completed.");
}
```

The relevant middleware code is as follows:

```
internal class ClientRateMiddleware : IClientRateThrottlingMiddleware
{
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        (...)
        Claim claim = context.User.FindFirst("client_id");
        // Claim is always null here because the Jwt handler has not run
        (...)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your API setup looks good to me and I would expect the Jwt handler to be invoked and the user/claims to be populated by the time it reaches your middleware. Is it possible the the bearer token is missing or invalid? You might try hooking into the JwtBearerEvents - message received, token validated - to trace what is happening.

Comment: I am sure that the Jwt handler is executed only when the [Authorize] filter is hit. I was able to implement a resource filter that implements what I want because it runs after the authorize filter. The problem with that approach is that it runs pretty late in the request processing. For a throttling component it should run as soon as possible.

Comment: That's strange - I'm having trouble reproducing this behavior in a simplified example. If I set the default scheme to "Bearer" and send a valid jwt in my request, then the user and claims are available to my next middleware in the pipeline. What else is going on in your `ConfigureServices()` method?

Comment: @Peter, I have updated the question to include all the code in ConfigureServices() and Configure().

Comment: Where you able to solve this?

Comment: This is really ancient. I did not solve it.

Comment: I too am facing this issue. If anyone has feedback, it would be much appreciated - .net 5

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I think I have kind of cracked this one. I think @Hugo Quintela Ribeiro is right about the authorization only occurring when the [Authorize] filter is hit, or when a controller that does not [Allow Anonymous] is hit in the case that authorization is set for the whole app. This of course happens at the controllers, and not in the middleware.

It turns out you can actually force authentication to occur in the middleware. I tried a couple of things like the following with no success.

```
await context.AuthenticateAsync();
await context.AuthenticateAsync("Custom"); //name of my jwt auth
```

In the end, I had to inject IAuthorizationPolicyProvider and IPolicyEvaluator to get the default policy and authenticate it.

```
using cpDataORM;
using cpDataServices.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace cpDataASP.Middleware
{
    public class LocalizationAndCurrencyMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public LocalizationAndCurrencyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }



        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IUserService _userService, ILoginContextAccessor loginContext, IAuthorizationPolicyProvider policyProvider, IPolicyEvaluator policyEvaluator)
        {
            var policy = await policyProvider.GetDefaultPolicyAsync();
            await policyEvaluator.AuthenticateAsync(policy, context);
            var localizationResources = await _userService.GetLocalizationResources();
            loginContext.Timezone = localizationResources.Timezone;
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = localizationResources.Culture;

            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
}
```